# Comment notification for a social site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a social networking site where users can chat to eachother, They also can post and comment on them but problem is occured when i am tried to send comment notifications to the users whose commented on post and post_author i have tried many times with different coding experience but i failed

This is local server running MySql ,PHP,and Apache

[This is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpXhs.png)
You Can see in the above image , There are 3 ids `post_id` on which post commented,`user_id` who has commented on the post and `author_id` this is `post_author id`, actually i want when `post_author` commented which is having `author_id = 3` then all the users who has commented on the particular post for example `user_id= 1 and 2` whose commented on `post_id = 58` should be notified except `user_id = 3`, and when `user_id = 2` commented on the same post then `author_id = 3` and `user_id = 1` should be notified1 i hope you understand what i want. Here is the code what i have tried.

```
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION['user_id']' ORDER BY com_id");

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
$notis = mysqli_fetch_all($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
foreach($notis as $noti){
$q2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id="'.$noti['user_id'].'""
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($q2);
$nick = $fetch['user_nick'];
}}
```

for example `$nick(John)Commented on your post`
And when another user commented on the same post for example `$nick(smith)commented on your post`
This code notify the post_author

i want to create notification chain for example when a user commented on a post then notify the post_author and also notify all users whose has commented on that post firstly.. and when post_author commented on his post then notify the all users whose commented on post..

if i try to send notifications to the users who has commented on a particular post

```
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id != '$_SESSION['user_id']' ORDER BY com_id");`

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
$notis = mysqli_fetch_all($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
foreach($notis as $noti){
$q2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id="'.$noti['user_id'].'""
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($q2);
$nick = $fetch['user_nick'];
}}
```

for example `$nick(John)Commented on his post`
this code notify all the users in the database except post_author

please help to create a proper comment notification what should be i do...

Comment: I would start by improving your database design. There must be a table with the posts in it, that will have a field like `author_id` in it. This means you don't need to repeat this field in your comments tables. You can use a query that joins the posts and comments tables to get the author.

Comment: i already have done it but It's not working properly

Comment: I removed you `Javascript` tag, and added `mysql`, that way the right people will see your question. It's basically a database question. You have trouble constructing the correct query. I noticed that you use the database column `user_nick` in your question, which is absent in the image of the comments table. You never explain what this column stands for.

Comment: `user_nick` is in another table `users` just for fetching user details it is a foreign key.. `user_nick` is just for example